# How to group null values separately?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Data:

```js
db={
  "Test": [
    {
      "x": "a"
    },
    {
      "x": "a",
      "y": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "a",
      "y": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

When aggregating like this:

```js
db.Test.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "x": "$x"
      },
      "y": {
        "$addToSet": "$y"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

... I expectedly get this:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "x": "a"
    },
    "y": [
      2,
      1
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want to group those `x`s separately where `y` is null and get this result:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "x": "a"
    },
    "y": []
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "x": "a"
    },
    "y": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  }
]
```

Is this possible?

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ri8ZLtpQRR)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/knJIT7JSdD4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZD66NxBMfFz)

```
db.Test.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "x": "$x",
        "z": {
          $cond: [
            {$ifNull: ["$y", false]},
            true,
            false
          ]
        }
      },
      "y": {
        "$addToSet": "$y"
      }
    }
  }
])
```